# Absolute paths added to flatpak are skipped

Tags: flatpak

I'm attempting to let flatpak app BLAH have access to the host's `/usr/foo`, like so:

> flatpak run -v --filesystem=/usr/foo:ro com.blah.BLAH/x86_64/stable

I get the following output:

> F: skipping export for path /usr/java

And when I use `flatpak enter` to take a look around the sandbox I can't see `/usr/foo`.

I'm using flatpak version 0.99.3 on Fedora 28.

Comment: Are you running this as `sudo flatpak`?

Comment: @slm Nope, running `flatpak run` as a regular user.

Comment: How would it write to `/usr/foo` without being root?

Comment: @slm I get the same problem even if it's labeled read-only.  I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `host` value. It will give you access to your `/usr` but however the doc says that your host `/usr` directory will be mounted under `/var/run/host`. It mentions that `/usr` is blacklisted because the sandbox has it's own `/usr` so it may be the reason why it's not available in `filesystem` options other than `host` too.

See the doc here: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#filesystem-access