# Flatpak program can't see all directories

Tags: permissions, flatpak

I need a flatpak program (Ardour in this case) to see some music plugins (which are installed in /usr/lib/lv2) but I couldn't make it to see those directories.

[image: Ardour folder search]

I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086529/how-to-give-a-flatpak-app-access-to-a-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1) and tried FlatSeal but it didn't work either:
[image: FlatSeal permissions for Ardour]

The triangle says "Changed by the user". I guess it's a warning mechanism for not changing too much or knowing what you have changed.

I tried the command line approach in the above link but it didn't work either.

I'm using PopOs which is Ubuntu based. Deb version of Ardour isn't available in shop and it's hard to compile Ardour from scratch. Also I had similar troubles with other flatpak programs in the past (ex. Unity not seeing VS Code).

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer from another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/462408/absolute-paths-added-to-flatpak-are-skipped?rq=1):

> Your host `/usr` directory will be mounted under `/var/run/host`. It mentions that `/usr` is blacklisted because the sandbox has its own `/usr` so it may be the reason why it's not available in filesystem options other than host too.

Thus, I can find the directory I was looking for in `/var/run/host/usr/lib/lv2` instead of `/usr/lib/lv2`.